# docker контейнера на выделенном сервере

Tags: docker

Кто разбирается в docker? Можете мне подсказать саму концепцию, или вернее даже принцип работы нескольких докер контейнеров на выделенном сервере на хостинге? Имеются три контейнера:

docker_site - node.js/next.js

docker_api - node.js/express.js

docker_db - php/mysql

Я запускаю три контейнера на домене [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com). С docker_site пробрасываю порты 80:3000, с docker_api 80:9000, с docker_db 3306:3360

Теперь последует ряд возможно странных вопросов от человека, который еще не разобрался с докер и никогда не работал с удаленным сервером, но хочет понять принцип работы его контейнеров на сервере:

1. Каждый контейнер будет рассмотрен как отдельный сайт? А порты, что я прокидываю наружу не должны конфликтовать и будут работать в контексте [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com)?
2. Как мне при таком подходе сделать стартовую страницу отображением сервера next.js, контейнера docker_site? То есть http://www.my-domain.com - открывает стартовую страницу приложения на next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Каждый контейнер будет рассмотрен как отдельный сайт? А порты, что я прокидываю наружу не должны конфликтовать и будут работать в контексте [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com)?

Это зависит от конфигурации, но судя по тому, что вы описали, то да. У вас каждый контейнер должен быть замаплен на отдельный порт и этот порту будет выставлен наружу. Но так обычно не делают.

> Как мне при таком подходе сделать стартовую страницу отображением сервера next.js, контейнера docker_site? То есть http://www.my-domain.com - открывает стартовую страницу приложения на next.js

Насколько я понял все 3 контейнера - это одно приложение, next - FE, express - BE, mysql - база. Для решения этой проблемы, обычно контейнеры запускают не руками (хотя и так тоже можно), а при помощи `Docker Compose`, тогда эти контейнеры будут объединены в одну сеть (т.е. каждый контейнер будет иметь выделенный ip адрес и dns имя из этой сети и они смогут между собой соединяться).

В таком случает базу данных "выставлять наружу" вообще не нужно, т.е. не нужно указывать маппинг портов, т.к. к базе никто не должен подключаться за пределами вашего сервера. Это не безопасно, даже если у вас там есть пароли.

А для того, чтобы избежать конфликт портов, например FE и BE слушают один порт 80, можно воспользоваться proxy, например `nginx`, и настроить перенаправление:

- `www.my-domain.com` -> `next`
- `www.my-domain.com/api/` -> `api`

Comment: "Это зависит от конфигурации, но судя по тому, что вы описали, то да. У вас каждый контейнер должен быть замаплен на отдельный порт и этот порту будет выставлен наружу. Но так обычно не делают" А как делают?

Comment: @DenisLopatin описано ниже, после ответа на второй вопрос

Comment: да в таком случае и на api не нужно будет делать маппинг портов. Нужно сделать только для сайта. То есть 9000:80, то есть вынести порт 9000 наружу. Но по умолчанию http использует порт 80. Не особо силен в теме, но не будут же подключаться к сайту как www.some.com:9000 )) Не лучше ли будет вынести 80 порт? 80:80 С другой стороны npn run start от next.js запускается на 9000 порту, тем не менее будет отрабатывать, если развернуть проект на хостинге через ssh. Ведь так?

Comment: @DenisLopatin если вы не будете использовать прокси, то мапить api нужно, т.к. к нему должен иметь доступ пользователь, если будете использовать прокси, то можно вообще ничего не мапить кроме nginx